# open set wrt metric topology, what does it mean ??

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

what is the difference between an open set ( where one can simply note whether or not it includes its boundary points) and a set which is open with respect to a metric topology, Or how would we notice it like the way we notice inclusion of boundary points usually ?

My teacher never explained this to us but has given us a question concerning it .

Comment: The first is about manifolds, the second is about topological spaces which includes metric spaces.  The sentence begining with "Or" is hard to decipher.  An open set and its boundary are disjoint within topological spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to give an intuitive explanation:
So an open set is the same as a set that is open.
The most direct concept of an open set could come from sets like $(a,b) \subset \mathbb R$, which as you described that it does not include its boundary.

Then if we apply some abstraction, we find that what is essential to the concept of open could be established purely by distance - that is, given any set, if we have a well-defined distance function for any of two elements in that set, we get a "metric space". Then we could define open set as a set that all its elements are "interior points" of the set. So here, a set is open or not depends on what "distance function" you define.

But we could apply the abstraction even further - we find "open" itself is a very interesting concept, and could be related to lots of other interesting concepts (like continuous, separation, etc.). Thus for an arbitrary set if we define a collection of subsets, and call them open - that is a "topological space". So here, a set is open or not depends on if you define it as open or not (i.e. how you define your topology).

Comment: Huh?  An open set is a set that is open??  Altogether, did you say anything?

Comment: Anything wrong? They are referring to the same concept of "open", but "open" itself varies under different context.

Comment: There is no difference between open sets in topological spaces and metric spaces except for the clumbsy way the notion is handled.  Within manifolds with boundaries are there no some open sets that contain may have boundary points?  The boundary of a manifold is distinctly different than the topological boundary of a set.

Comment: @WilliamElliot “there is no difference between open sets in topological spaces and metric space” - that’s not quite accurate, maybe you mean that each metric space is a topological space, and it has a topology naturally generated by its metric function. I do not know why you want to mention manifold here separately, a manifold is a topological space in the first place. Lastly, we could discuss open set and boundaries (like the other answer did), but to understand the concept of open, we do not need to involve boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

A subset $ U$ of a top'l space $S$ is open  iff $U\cap \partial U=\emptyset,$ where $\partial U$ is the boundary of $U.$ That is, $\partial U=\overline U\cap \overline {(S \setminus U)}.$ The notation Fr$(U)$ is also used for $\partial U.$ ("Fr" is for "Frontier".)

(i).Suppose $U$ is open. Then  $S$ \ $U =\overline {S \setminus U}$ so $$U\cap \partial U=U\cap (\;\overline U\cap \overline {S \setminus U}\;)=$$ $$=U\cap (\;\overline U\cap (S \setminus U)\;)=$$ $$=(U\cap \overline U)\cap (S \setminus U)=$$ $$=U\cap (S \setminus U)= \emptyset.$$

(ii). Suppose $U\cap \partial U=\emptyset.$ Then $U\subset S\setminus (\overline {S\setminus U})$ because $$\emptyset=U\cap (\;\overline U \cap \overline {S \setminus U}\;)=$$ $$=(U\cap \overline U)\cap (\overline {S\setminus U})=$$ $$=U\cap (\overline {S\setminus U}).$$  .Also $\overline {S\setminus U}\supset S\setminus U$. So we have  $$U\subset S \setminus (\overline {S\setminus U}))\subset S \setminus (S\setminus U)) =U.$$ Therefore $U=S \setminus \overline {(S\setminus U)}.$ That is, $S$ is the complement of the closed set $\overline {S\setminus U},$ so $U$ is open.